# Can Static Objects (such as Singletons) leak non-static Context? Why?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

This might sound like a silly question, but I'm flipping between two design models of a singleton and POJO that accesses Shared Prefs, and I want to prevent any mem. leaks in terms of context.

I know static objects are allocated to the heap, but for say a singleton design where the **class** remains unstatic and declares a *static* instance of itself and instantiates it, if this instance is passed context to do some type of method,

- can it leak this context?
- If not why not, if yes why and how could it be fixed?

Here's a current singleton design I've created

```
public class UserSettings {
  private UserSettings settings = new UserSettings();

  private UserSettings() {
    }

    public static UserSettings getInstance() {
        return settings;
    }

    private SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(
                USER_SETTINGS_FILE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        );
    }

    private SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(
                USER_SETTINGS_FILE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        ).edit();
    }

    public Object get(Context context,int item) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getPrefs(context);
        switch (item) {
            case TIMING:
                return sp.getInt(KEY_USER_TIMING,60);
            case NAME:
                return sp.getString(KEY_USER_NAME,"Stranger");
            // .. etc
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public void update(Context context,int setting, Object updateValue) throws ClassCastException {
        SharedPreferences.Editor sp = getPrefs(context).edit();
        switch (setting) {
            case TIMING:
                if (Integer.class.isInstance(updateValue))
                    sp.putInt(KEY_USER_TIMING,(int)updateValue).commit();
                else
                    throw new ClassCastException("User Time must be int");
                break;
            case NAME:
                if (String.class.isInstance(updateValue))
                    sp.putString(KEY_USER_NAME,(String)updateValue).commit();
                else
                    throw new ClassCastException("User Name must be String");
                break;
           // .... etc
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Instances aren't static, references are. Objects are just objects. There can exist both static and non-static references to the same object. So statements like "static objects are allocated to [sic] the heap" are incorrect. All objects are allocated on the heap, conceptually (but not always actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not creating a reference to a context but passing it in to each method call, it can't leak because it's not being retained. You would only be leaking a context if you stored a reference to it outside of its lifecycle. For instance, if I store use Activity context to initialize a singleton statically. Even when the Activity goes away, the context object won't be finalized because there's still a reference to it somewhere.

However, there are several design patterns to accomplish this neatly. I generally use [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger)

This doesn't result in a context leak, because the lifecycle of your Singleton SharedPreferencesHelper is tied to the lifecycle of your application and it uses the application context.

CustomApplication.java

```
private static ObjectGraph staticRefToObjectGraph;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    staticRefToObjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MyModule(this));
}

public static void inject(Object obj) {
    staticRefToObjectGraph.inject(obj);
}
```

MyModule.java

```
public MyModule(Context applicationContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
    prefsHelper = new SharedPreferencesHelper(prefs);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public SharedPreferencesHelper providePrefsHelper() {
    return prefsHelper;
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
@Inject SharedPreferencesHelper prefsHelper

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyApplication.performInjection(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer JCSG, and the suggestion for dagger.

How applicable would Dagger be for a situation like the following: 

My application itself is usually never open (ie. Activities is rarely ever Live) rather the entire application runs over a consistent background service. 

Would the context then be bounded to the Service? (this is why I struggle and don't think I can use application context in my case)?

Comment: It would work exactly the same for a service. The application context is the application context. The service would get the same instance of SharedPreferencesHelper as an activity would.

Comment: Just as one final comment before I mark accepted. 

Based on what you've described the Application is the all encompassing Object representing my app itself, meaning that while any component of the Application, be it a service or activity is alive, then the Application object itself is alive. Such that passing ApplicationContext is legal in any one of these alive services or activities?

Comment: Correct, if *any* piece of your application code is running -- a service, a broadcast receiver, an activity, etc -- the application context has been created before anything else and is active.